# C# shorthand for Equals() when both args can be null

Tags: c#, null, equals

A simple question:

I want to compare two objects using the virtual Equals() method (not `==`). Both can be null.

Should I repeat this litany:

```
if ((left == null && right == null) || (left != null && left.Equals(right)) {

}
```

or is there a more elegant idiom for such situation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yup:

```
if (object.Equals(left, right))
```

or even without making it obvious that it's calling the static method:

```
if (Equals(left, right))
```

(Personally I prefer the extra clarity though.)

The static [`object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method doesn't have terribly good documentation, but it does exactly what you want :)

Comment: I had to look at the example to be sure that it really does what is wanted :-)

Comment: I'm curious, why does the second example even compile?

Comment: @KendallFrey: I don't understand the question. Why do you think it should *not* compile?

Comment: Thanks, I kind of didn't expect the static `object.Equals` to trigger polymorphic behaviour. :-) BTW Out of curiosity, will this also behave correctly if it's generic code and `left` and `right` are of generic argument type, i.e. possibly structs?

Comment: @Kos: I don't quite understand your question either. If left and right happen to be structs then they will be boxed; is that what you're getting at?

Comment: @KendalFrey: `object` in C# is short for `Object` which is in the System namespace which probably is included at the top of the file with a `using System;`

Comment: @Eric: I suppose it would implicitly do `ThisClass.Equals`, which maps to `object.Equals` or something? It just seems to be posing as a global method, which is wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert Nevermind, I forgot that `ValueType` is `Object` too. No more worries :-)

Comment: @KendallFrey: Every method of `object` is also a method of every type that inherits from `object` -- that's what "inherits" means. Static methods are inherited like every other method.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, I think I get it now. When I first looked at it, it seemed very wrong.

Comment: The static object.Equals method will simply do the proper null checking and then call the instance `Equals` method using the given parameters.  The static method itself isn't virtual, nor is it overridden by any other classes.

Comment: @LosManos `Equals(x, y)` will compile even without `using System;`.  `using System;` is required for `Object.Equals(x, y)` to compile, however.